# Вывести массива в select

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести значение массива  в select. Когда я вывожу оно делится на 3 столбика(red,blue,green). Как вывести каждый объекты в отдельную строку(что бы каждое название было в отдельной строке)?

```js
let selLine = document.querySelector('#selectLine');

const metro = {
 "red" : [
   'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
   ],
 "blue" : [
   'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
 ],
 "green" : [
   'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
 ]
}

let massVal = Object.values(metro);
for( let i = 0; i < massVal.length; i++) {
 selLine.add(new Option(massVal[i]));
}
```

```html
<select id="selectLine"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно обойти массив вложенным циклом

```
for (var key in metro) {
   for( var elem in metro[key]) {
    selLine.add(metro[key][elem]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Используем вложенный цикл**

```
 let selLine = document.querySelector('#selectLine');

        const metro = {
            "red" : [
            'Академгородок', 'Житомирская', 'Святошин', 'Нивки',
            ],
            "blue" : [
            'ТЧ-2 «Оболонь»', 'Героев Днепра', 'Оболонь', 'Почайна',
            ],
            "green" : [
            'Сырец', 'Дорогожичи', 'Герцена', 'Лукьяновская',
            ]
        }

        function CustomOption(text, value, selected) {
            this.text = text || 'Choose one option';
            this.value = value || 'Choose one option';
            this.selected = selected || false;
        };

        let massVal = Object.values(metro);
        console.log(massVal);
        for( let i = 0; i < massVal.length; i++) {
            let newOption = new CustomOption(massVal[i], massVal[i]);
            for (let j = 0; j < massVal.length; j++) {
                selLine.add(new Option(massVal[i][j]));
            }
        }
```